# Spark - Which instance type is preferred for AWS EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, emr

I am running some machine learning algorithms on EMR Spark cluster. I am curious about which kind of instance to use so I can get the optimal cost/performance gain?

For the same level of prices, I can choose among:

```
          vCPU  ECU  Memory(GiB)
m3.xlarge  4     13     15     
c4.xlarge  4     16      7.5
r3.xlarge  4     13     30.5
```

Which kind of instance should be used in EMR Spark cluster?

Comment: it depends on your use case, needs, etc...  (quite opinion based QA)

Comment: Just for instance, what if I am going to train an ALS factorization or SVD on matricies with several millions of entries?

Comment: What size is your data? in Gigabytes?

Comment: Yes, hundreds of megabytes to several gigabytes.

Comment: So what is the size?

Comment: the training dataset, 2~4 gigabytes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78706/discussion-between-eliasah-and-shihpeng).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generally speaking, it depends on your use case, needs, etc... But I can suggest a minimum configuration considering the information that you have shared.

You seem to be trying to train an `ALS` factorization or `SVD` on matrices between 2 ~ 4 GBs of data. So actually that's not too much of data.

You'll be needing at least 1 master and 2 nodes to setup and configure a small distributed cluster. The master won't be doing any computing whatsoever so it won't need much resources but of course I would be dealing task scheduling, etc.

You can add slaves (instances) according to your needs.

- 1 x master  : <strike>m3.xlarge</strike> **m5.xlarge** - vCPU : 4 , RAM : 16 GB with EBS storage.
- 2 x slaves  : <strike>c3.4xlarge</strike> **c5.xlarge**   - vCPU : 16, RAM : 32 GB with EBS storage.

**EDIT :** As mentioned in the comments, 5th generation instances are now available for each of the instance types mentioned in this thread: R5, M5, and C5. In general, latest-generation instance types are cheaper and more performant than their older counterparts.

C3, C4, and C5 are *compute optimized* instances featuring high performance processors and with a lowest price/compute performance in EC2 compared to R3, R4 or R5 although it's recommended use cases are distributed memory caches and in-memory analytics. But C5 will do the job for you for a lower price.

> **Performance Optimizations :**
>
> - Amazon EMR charges on hourly increments. This means once you run a cluster, you are paying for the entire hour. That's important to remember because if you are paying for a full hour of Amazon EMR cluster, improving your data processing time by matter of minutes may not be worth your time and effort.
> - Don't forget that adding more nodes to increase performance is cheaper than spending time optimizing your cluster.
>
> Reference :  [Amazon EMR Best Practices - Parviz Deyhim](https://d0.awsstatic.com/International/fr_FR/whitepapers/aws-amazon-emr-best-practices.pdf.pdf).

**EDIT :** You might also consider enabling [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) to monitor your cluster resources: CPU, RAM, Network I/O. This would help you also tuning your EMR cluster. Practically, you don't have any configuration to do. Just follow the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-ganglia.html) to add it to your EMR cluster on creation.

Comment: I'd like to point out to anyone seeing this in 2018 -- 5th generation instances are now available for each of the instance types mentioned in this thread: R5, M5, and C5. In general, latest-generation instance types are cheaper and more performant than their older counterparts.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking the preferred instance depends on the job you are running (is it memory intensive? is it CPU intensive? etc.) However Spark is very memory intensive and I wouldn't use machines with less than 30Gb for most jobs.

In your particular case (4Gb dataset) I am not sure why you'd want to use distributed computing to begin with- it will just make your job run slow. If you are sure you want spark run it in local mode with X threads (depending on how many cores you have)

Comment: I agree with you and that why I said minimum conf. :)

Comment: The minimum conf is not to use EMR - just get an instance (even a spot instance) download spark and run it in local mode

Comment: Minimum conf for EMR, the question was about Spark on EMR I suppose. Have a nice day!

Comment: Indeed. It is just that in my opinion it would be wasteful for him to run on EMR. He'd get a cheaper (and faster) solution running on a single machine .Nice day to you too ! :)

Comment: Actually before doing the real training work on the dataset, we need to preprocess the raw data, which is about 20~30GB (after process, the data becomes much smaller), the volume is not feasible for a single instance (take ~20 minute), so we use EMR to do the whole data process + training work.

Comment: 30GB is feasible for a single node - a cc2.8xlarge spot instance (32 vcpus, 60GB ram) cost around 20 cents per hour.  I would hardly think adding coordination, serialization (of both code and data) and network latencies would  handle 30GB worth of data faster. You may want to read http://aadrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html (for example)

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz nice suggestion, I will test my while process on a bigger instance!